# JPA/Hibernate - updating database schema after changing PK of an entity

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I need to change the primary key (@Id) of an entity from natural key to a new field that represents a surrogate key (it will use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)`).
What is the easiest way to update the database schema other than dropping the table and letting Hibernate to create it again?
I was trying to let Hibernate update the schema automagically with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` set to `update`, but it didn't work out. I suppose that Hibernate autoupdate doesn't support such drastic changes of database schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were only one entity, I'd

- make the changes in the database manually (SQL)
- and update the Hibernate mapping accordingly